# Java: Simple recursion function returns only 1

Tags: java, algorithm, factorial

This is oddly my first Java application, I was wanting to implement an arbitrary precision factorial function, I did the recursive one fine but my iterative one simply outputs "1" and nothing else.. It is so late for me I can not spot why, I am not sure where I went wrong, is there something obvious here?

```
public static BigInteger ifact(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger ret = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger i = new BigInteger("1");
    for(i = new BigInteger("0"); i.compareTo(n) == 0; i.add(new BigInteger("1"))){
        ret.multiply(i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

In case you did not notice it uses the BigInteger package, hense the odd writings..

Also, like C, can you do something similar to typedef so I don't need to type "BigInteger" each time?

**EDIT**: I think I meant to set `ret` as `n`, that may be it, or..maybe not.

Comment: Also note that there's a constant BigInteger.ONE which avoids needing to create a new "1" every time.

Comment: Also BigInteger.ZERO, even TEN. And there's `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` for all the rest...if it's hardcoded, don't use Strings.

Comment: Recursion? I see a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to your "typedef" question, no, you can't do that in Java.

As for your code, it has numerous mistakes.  Your loop will only ever execute once, and only if n is equal to i.  Why do you initialize i to 1 and then 0 at the beginning of the loop?  Why do you ignore the result of `i.add(...)`?  Why do you ignore the result of `ret.multiply(i)`?  Remember, these methods don't change the BI itself!

This incorporates those changes:

```
    BigInteger n = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
    BigInteger ret = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(n) <= 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        ret = ret.multiply(i);
    }
    System.out.println(ret);
```

Comment: I keep thinking the statements = another statement, not just a function with a return value. I'll fix my stupid mistakes and update if I need any more help.. man I should not code at 6am..

Comment: I thank you alot for the example, that answers my question completely. I was up for the past 20 hours, a new language is hard to learn under this circumstance.. I kept fixing the code and not the logic.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing

```
ret.multiply(i);
```

to

```
ret = ret.multiply(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

The BigInteger object is immutable (meaning you can't change it). In this way, it's like a String object. So, for this to work, you would want to change your line

```
ret.multiply(i);
```

to

```
ret = ret.multiply(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static BigInteger ifact(BigInteger n) {
  BigInteger ret = BigInteger.ONE;
  for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(n) <= 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    ret = ret.multiply(i);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

1. ret = ret.multiply
2. i.compareTo(n) <= 0
3. BigInteger.ONE;